# Does ResultSet.Next() skip rows?

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm running unto a problem with the [ResultSet.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) method in Java.
The following code connects to a SQLite database file and attempts to read all the tables contained in the db.

```
    // Set the connection up with jdbc and sqlite.
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:file.db");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.setQueryTimeout(30);

    // Get all the tables in the DB so we can check that we have all we need.
    ResultSet trs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master  WHERE type='table';");
    while (trs.next()) {
        String tblname = trs.getString("name").toLowerCase();
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Found table: " + tblname);
    }
```

The database contains 2 tables (verified by running the query in the sqlite3 client), but the while loop only does one iteration before exiting.

Any suggestions as to why the last table gets ignored?

Comment: You should use preparedStatement.. Apart do you get any row when you fire that query?

Comment: @SMA - Using prepared statements doesn't change the result. But if it's better etiquette, I'll go with that.
I get the first row of the results, but not the second.

The db contains the tables "users" and "probes". But the loop above only prints the "probes" string.

Comment: You should use the [standard API method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-) instead of a database-specific query. However, that’s not causing the problem. As your code is incomplete and doesn’t even contain the entire loop, there’s little we can say about this, besides the fact that `ResultSet.next()` is an *interface* method which is implemented by the database driver, hence, the Java version shouldn’t matter.

Comment: @Holger - Ah, I did not see that method. I'll look into that instead.
Will you make an answer for it so I can mark it, or should I do it myself?
It renders the current question pretty moot, so I'm unsure of wether or not this is the correct way to go with regards to closing the question/thread?

Comment: Does it solve your problem? While it is the recommended way of doing it,it doesn’t explain why your attempt doesn’t work…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Holgers suggestions (see comments for question) I switched to the API method [getTables()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-) instead.

```
// Set the connection up with jdbc and sqlite.
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:file.db");

// Get the tables.
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet trs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (trs.next()) {
            String tblname = trs.getString("TABLE_NAME").toLowerCase();
            log.log(Level.INFO, "Found table: " + tblname);
}
```

This solves my problem with not getting all the tables in the ResultSet.